# How to insert an internal class id into a href link in Angular 8? .html component

Tags: angular

Apologies as I am quite new to Angular.

I've been trying to pass an ID from a div in the same html file as my href link is.

Basically what I am trying to achieve is to have a photo on my website, and upon clicking on it, a text relevant to a photo will appear. I have used the click function but it still isn't working. Can someone please advise as to where I am going wrong with this?

If this was done outside of angular, with just html and css, it would simply work by inserting #p1 in a href link (the id from the next div)

My html  a href code snippet:

```
<a href="p1"(click)="viewDoc()"><img src="" alt=""></a>
```

My html (same page) div id code snippet:

```
<div class="section" id="p1">
```

My ts code snippet:

```
clicked=true;
  viewDoc():void{
    this.clicked=!this.clicked;
```

Again, just to explain better, it this was css and html on its own, the following code would suffice:

```
<a href="#p1"><img src="" alt=""></a>
```

Can someone please help me with getting this work in Angualar 8?

Comment: So when you click on the anchor tag, a text should appear, so where is that text ? you question is not clear.

Comment: Apologies, the text is under the div class"section" in a paragraph, so it would be as follows:  <div class="section" id="p1">
        <span class="name">Text</span>
        <span class="border"></span>
        <p>Text.  </p>
      </div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML File

```
 <div>
      <a href="/componentroutepath#p1"><img src="" alt="" />Click Me</a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="section" id="p1">
      <span class="name">Text</span> <span class="border"></span>
    </div>
```

So, when you will click on the button, you can toggle the text.

Comment: Thank you for this! See it is still missing the Href or routerlink and so when I click on the image, it doesn't take me anywhere while it should take me to p1. I tried to insert href="p1" so it would look like this : <a href="p1" (click)="viewDoc()"><img src="" alt="" />Click Me</a>  but it doesn't work. Sorry for all the questions!

Comment: Your question wasn't clear, so you want to route to p1? P1 is a different component ? If you want to route to a different component, then you can use routerLink.

Comment: Hi, p1 is in same HTML file, I am trying to do https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DNiGz7Zxk2Y&t=337s min 6:25 of this video

Comment: If it helped you please upvote the answer, so that it will help others too !